# Return SQL one to many / one to many all in one PHP array / object?

Tags: php, sql, one-to-many

`tbl_customers

customer_id INT

...

...`

`tbl_orders

order_id

customer_id`

tbl_orders_products
product_id
order_id

Suppose I want to access all the products ordered on all the orders by one customer?
Is it possible to return this in one PHP array using just 1 SQL query (MySQL db)?

Expected result:

> array(
>
> > [customer_id] => 1,
> >     [orders] => array(
> >
> > > [0] => array(
> > >
> > > > [order_id] => [1],
> > > >         [products] => array(
> > > >
> > > > > [0] => array(
> > > > >
> > > > > > [product_name] => 'widget')
> > >
> > > )
> > >       )
> > >       )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible.

you could use left joins between each table, but each row would have all of the user info and order info, along with the item specific info

```
example result rows
user_id, username, order_id, product_id_1
user_id, username, order_id, product_id_2
user_id, username, order_id, product_id_3
```

you could then format this into the desired array.

Comment: Thanks forr the reply. I can do as you show but is it possible to return those as arrays within the results so your example is all one row with the last column as array(product_id_1, product_id_2, etc.)? Maybe a nested query or subquery or is this impossible?